# Pandas - string split into multiple columns with variable number of delimited values into 3 columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have string series that can contain strings of the form `a[ - b[ - c]]` square brackets implying optionally present. For example it can either be in the form `a` or `a - b` or `a - b - c`. I want to extract each element and convert it to a dataframe with 3 columns.

Now if the series has all 3 formats this gives the right result

```py
s = pd.Series(['a', 'a - b', 'a - b - c'])
s.str.split(' - ', expand=True).fillna('')
# out
   0  1  2
0  a
1  a  b
2  a  b  c
```

However if it is just `s = pd.Series(['a', 'a - b'])` then I just get

```
   0  1
0  a
1  a  b
```

expected output in this case would be

```py
   0  1 2
0  a
1  a  b
```

I want 3 columns in the output regardless of what types of patterns are present in the series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
s.str.split(' - ', expand=True).reindex(range(3), axis=1).astype(object).mask(lambda x: x.isna(), None)
```

Or:

```
s.str.split(' - ', expand=True).reindex(range(3), axis=1).fillna('')
```

Comment: You'll need to convert to `object` before you can `mask` in the `None` values (otherwise they'll stay as NaN since the dtype of the columns is float), however, I really like the workaround for putting the None. Use -> `s.str.split(' - ', expand=True).reindex(range(3), axis=1).astype(object).mask(lambda x: x.isna(), None)`

Comment: It's okay. I was writing the `reindex` answer but I was struggling to get the `None`s right. Pandas really doesn't like handling anything other than NaN. I wouldn't have thought of the mask with lambda so I'm happy we got it together :)